# Standalone video control example for Google TV jQuery Library?

Tags: html5-video, google-tv

The jQuery VideoControl is documented here:
https://developers.google.com/tv/web/lib/jquery/#gtv.jq.VideoControl

It takes a set of VideoParms.  That are not specified.

It is used in the sample templates on this page:
https://developers.google.com/tv/web/docs/gtv-templates

I've taken apart the templates, but I'm having difficulty creating a simple example of a standalone video control.  In the templates, the sidenav and carousel code are tied to how the videocontrol works.  There is a relationship between the keyController and behavior (behaviorZones) that I can not find an explanation for.

Is there a standalone example somewhere?  What needs to be setup with keycontroller, css, and behavior to get this going?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware that there is a standalone videocontrol.js sample but it should be possible to set it up.  Most of the necessary pieces are inside videocontrol.js, in particular in the videocontrol's constructor and this function: gtv.jq.VideoControl.prototype.makeControl.

keycontroller mapping is used to handling key inputs and some of the CSS are dynamically controlled within JS so there might be errors if you just rip them apart straight from the Template.  You'd have to debug it using a solid tool like Chrome Developer Tools.  You can watch tutorials of this tool here: http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=chrome+developer+tools&oq=chrome+develop&aq=0&aqi=g3g-m2&aql=&gs_sm=3&gs_upl=1972l4015l0l6142l14l11l0l0l0l0l207l1476l3.5.3l11l0

Otherwise please send your error traces and/or code snippet for debugging help.

- S

Comment: Thanks, I've been ripping apart the javascript and html.  I have a minimal example, but may be missing something from the CSS.  

I believe I am OK on the makeControl side.  Also getting data for the video.  The issue is playing the video.  In the demo example, the function makeTab creates tooltips and carousel elements.  It is intimately tied to displaying the video.